# Help with this demostration of spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let $U, W, S$ dimensional subspaces of a finite space such that $V=U+W+S$. Prove that $V = U\oplus W\oplus S$ if and only if
$\dim (V) = \dim (U) + \dim (W) + \dim (S)$.

Comment: There is no question here. What is your problem? What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\Longrightarrow)$ Suppose that $V=U \oplus W \oplus S$.

Then, 
\begin{split}
dim(V) &= dim((U \oplus W) \oplus S) \\
&= dim(U \oplus W) + dim(S) - dim((U \oplus W) \cap S).
\end{split}

As $$(U \oplus W) \cap S = \{0\}$$ (because we have a direct sum), we have $$dim(V) = dim(U \oplus W) + dim(S).$$

Again, $$dim(U \oplus W) = dim(U) + dim(W).$$

Then, $$dim(V) = dim(U) + dim(W) + dim(S).$$

> $\Longleftarrow)$ Suppose that $dim(V)=dim(U)+dim(W)+dim(S)$.

We have 
\begin{split}
dim(V) &= dim(U+W+S) \\
&= dim((U+W)+S) \\
&= dim(U+W)+dim(S)-dim((U+W)\cap S) \\
&= dim(U)+dim(W)-dim(U \cap W)+dim(S)-dim((U+W) \cap S).
\end{split}

Then, $$0=dim(U \cap W)+dim((U+W) \cap S).$$

So $$dim(U \cap W) = 0$$ and $$dim((U+W) \cap S)=0.$$

Then,
\begin{split}
V = (U + W) \oplus S &= (U \oplus W) \oplus S \\
&= U \oplus W \oplus S.
\end{split}